# Oracle - change columns in WHERE clause based on input

Tags: oracle, case, where-clause, multiple-columns, tablecolumn

I want use separate columns in WHERE clause based on the INPUT received in the stored procedure.

- If TYPE_DEFINITION = 'SUP' then use SUPPLIER column
- If TYPE_DEFINITION = 'CAT' then use CATEGORY column

I know I can write two separate `SELECT`'s using a `CASE` statement, but that will be very dumb and redundant. Any cleaner way of doing it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SG.STORED_PROCEDURE (
   TYPE_DEFINITION     IN VARCHAR2,
   VALUE               IN VARCHAR2,
   STORELIST           IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
      SELECT O.ORGNUMBER,
             S.SKU,
        FROM SKU S JOIN ORG O ON S.ORGID = O.ORGID
       WHERE                   
             AND O.ORGNUMBER IN (STORELIST)
             AND (CASE TYPE_DEFINITION
                     WHEN 'SUP' THEN S.SUPPLIER = VALUE
                     ELSE S.CATEGORY = VALUE
                  END);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) in your procedure.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SG.STORE_PROC (
   TYPE_DEFINITION     IN VARCHAR2,
   VALUE               IN VARCHAR2,
   STORELIST           IN VARCHAR2)
AS
  TYPE EmpCurTyp  IS REF CURSOR;
  v_emp_cursor    EmpCurTyp;
  v_stmt_str      VARCHAR2(200);
  v_orgnumber     VARCHAR2(200);
  v_sku           VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_stmt_str := 'SELECT O.ORGNUMBER, S.SKU,FROM SKU S JOIN ORG O ON S.ORGID = O.ORGID ';
  if type_definition = 'SUP' then
     v_stmt_str := v_stmt_str || 'WHERE s.supplier = :v';
  else
     v_stmt_str := v_stmt_str || 'WHERE s.category = :v';
  end if;


  -- Open cursor & specify bind variable in USING clause:
  OPEN v_emp_cursor FOR v_stmt_str USING value;

  -- Fetch rows from result set one at a time:
  LOOP
    FETCH v_emp_cursor INTO v_orgnumber, v_sku;
    -- you can do something here with your values
    EXIT WHEN v_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;

  -- Close cursor:
  CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very close.  The `CASE` `THEN` must return an expression, not a condition.  But the `CASE` can be used as part of a condition, just move the `= VALUE`
 to the outside.

Change this:

```
         AND (CASE TYPE_DEFINITION
                 WHEN 'SUP' THEN S.SUPPLIER = VALUE
                 ELSE S.CATEGORY = VALUE
              END);
```

To This:

```
         AND VALUE = (CASE TYPE_DEFINITION
                         WHEN 'SUP' THEN S.SUPPLIER
                         ELSE S.CATEGORY
                      END);
```

Your code makes sense.  This limitation is probably a result of Oracle not fully supporting Booleans.

---

**UPDATE**

If you run into performance problems you may want to use dynamic SQL or ensure that the static SQL is correctly using `FILTER` operations.  When Oracle builds an execution plan it is able to use bind variables like constants, and choose a different plan based on the input.  As Ben pointed out, these `FILTER` operations don't always work perfectly, sometimes it may help if you use simplified conditions like this:

```
(TYPE_DEFINITION = 'SUP' AND S.SUPPLIER = VALUE)
OR
((TYPE_DEFINITION <> 'SUP' OR TYPE_DEFINITION IS NULL) AND S.CATEGORY = VALUE)
```

Comment: You can do this, and for a single condition it would be fine, but for anything moderately complex (i.e. if there are more than a handful of conditional pieces of logic) then you might get some funky plans. My recommendation would be that for anything more than three or four dynamic conditions, you use dynamic SQL. That way you get individually tunable query plans and the optimiser stands a better chance of predicting good strategies.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, that's a good point.  I added some information about dealing with bad plans with static SQL and multiple conditions.